# Sort newest date time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to sort array to the newest date time, but im getting error like "sort is not a function"

[image: My array]

here's my code :

```
const { userCommissionHistoryState, userCommissionDebitHistoryState, userCommissionCreditHistoryState } = this.state
const payload =
  !userCommissionHistoryState.fetching && userCommissionHistoryState.success && !_.isEmpty(userCommissionHistoryState.data)
    ? userCommissionHistoryState.data
    : {}

    payload.sort(function(a,b){
      return new Date(a.created_at) - new Date(b.created_at)
    })
```

Comment: you need an array for sorting.

Comment: can you please check my image? is there an array?

Comment: Please provide your example array as code, not as image. thank you

Comment: 0:
agent_id: 58
amount: 90000
created_at: "2019-08-02T04:02:26.611Z"
reference: "WBZ98354852229-1"
remark: "Top-up manual by firman"
transaction_type: "credit"

Comment: If updating endpoint to return an array isn't possible, then `Object.values(payload)...` may help as it returns an array of the payload object's values that you can then sort or call any other array functions on.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```js
const payload =
  !userCommissionHistoryState.fetching && userCommissionHistoryState.success && !_.isEmpty(userCommissionHistoryState.data)
    ? userCommissionHistoryState.data
    : {}
```

I'm not sure about type of `userCommissionHistoryState.data`, but type of `{}` is an object, not an array. There is no `sort()` method in `Object.prototype`. Probably, you need to replace `{}` with `[]` and adjust `userCommissionHistoryState.data` to be an array (for instance, using `Object.values` if you need values of some object).

Also, maybe it's better to clone `userCommissionHistoryState.data` array, otherwise `sort()` function will mutate it.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the payload variable value will be an object instead of array

Replace

```
!userCommissionHistoryState.fetching && userCommissionHistoryState.success && !_.isEmpty(userCommissionHistoryState.data)
    ? userCommissionHistoryState.data
    : {}
```

with

```
!userCommissionHistoryState.fetching && userCommissionHistoryState.success && !_.isEmpty(userCommissionHistoryState.data)
    ? userCommissionHistoryState.data
    : []
```

Comment: im getting error, because the data is immutable

Comment: you can use `userCommissionHistoryState.data.slice()` to create a copy